# Access @native methods from sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to access information of the compile task in sbt. Specifically, my goal is to get a list of all methods in all classes that have the `@native` annotation.

To get started, I explored the `Analysis` API:

```
//print some info about the build structure
def printDefinition(definition: xsbti.api.Definition): Unit = definition match {
  case classDef: xsbti.api.ClassLike =>
    println("class " + classDef.name())
    classDef.structure.declared.foreach{ d =>
      printDefinition(d)
    }
  case otherDef: xsbti.api.Definition =>
    println("other: " + otherDef.name())
}

//list all declarations
compile := {
  val analysis = (compile in Compile).value
  analysis.apis.internal.foreach{ case (file, source) =>
    source.api().definitions() foreach printDefinition
  }
  analysis
}
```

Unfortunately however, any `@native` methods aren't listed. The compiler doesn't generate code for native methods, my guess is that they are therefore omitted from sbt's report. However, since a `classDef.structure` has a `declared` field (as opposed to `defined` or `implemented`), I was wondering if this is a bug and/or if there are alternative ways to list all methods with said annotation?

Comment: This is what I do https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin/blob/master/src/NativeFinder.scala

Comment: If sbt does not provide a way to hook into its compiler out-of-the-box its definitely a viable alternative. Thanks for the link

Comment: I imagine the main problem is that @native compiles down to a modifier and not an annotation.

Comment: Thanks to your link, I implemented something similar: https://github.com/jodersky/sbt-jni/blob/a9864a8b9b6c5b49f5cd79bb1ba3b325d702f67f/jni-plugin/src/main/scala/ch/jodersky/sbt/jni/util/ByteCode.scala